# Does this matrix have strictly positive eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a square matrix $A$ with real entries and a diagonal matrix $B$ with strictly positive elements. Assume that the symmetric part of $A$, i.e. $\displaystyle \frac{A^T+A}{2}$, has strictly positive eigenvalues.

Does the symmetric part of $BA$, i.e. $\displaystyle\frac{(BA)^T+BA}{2}$, also have strictly positive eigenvalues?

Comment: Remember, in a diagonal matrix the eigenvalues can be read directly off of the diagonal entries.  So does multiplying positive eigenvalues result in positive eigenvalues?

Comment: @StevenWalton There is a subtlety here in that $BA$ is not symmetric (even when $A$ is).  Although the product of positive definite matrices has positive eigenvalues, its symmetric part might not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 100 \\ -100&1\end{bmatrix}$.  For any $B$ that isn't very close to a multiple of the identity, multiplying by $B$ will create an imbalance in the off-diagonal entries, causing the symmetric part of $BA$ to have negative determinant.